# Should c.tld and fmt.tld be committed to version control?

Tags: grails

Should these files be committed to version control, or do they get regenerated:

```
web-app/WEB-INF/tld/c.tld
web-app/WEB-INF/tld/fmt.tld
```

`grails integrate-with --git` doesn't seem to think so and I wonder why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are indeed automatically generated when you run `grails war` or `grails run-app` (see [GRAILS-7802](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-7802)).

Though I've commited them to git and it has never really bothered me -- these files usually don't change.